# How to write Mongoose Queries with optional express query-params?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am building a REST API on top of Express 4. For a path lets say `GET /api/users` I want to query my users collection accordingly to ***optional***  queryParams.

So a call to the API could look like this `host:port/api/users?city=Berlin`

In this case `name` is omitted and doesn't influence the query, whereas `city` has to match.

I managed to do this with the following hack. Is there a better way than that?

```
Users.statics.customFilter = function(qP){
    return this.find({
        $and: [
            {$or: [{undefined: {$eq: qP.city}}, {'city': qP.city}]},
            {$or: [{undefined: {$eq: qP.name}}, {'name': qP.name}]}
        ]
    });

mongoose.model('User', Users);
```

I'm calling this static function from the mongoose schema like this...

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');
app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
        User.customFilter(req.query)
        .exec((err, results) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(results);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57001644/how-to-filter-results-by-multiple-query-parameters-if-i-dont-know-beforehand-ho

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that in essence, `User.find(req.query)` should do what you want:

```
/api/users?city=Berlin           → User.find({ city : 'Berlin' })
/api/users?name=John             → User.find({ name : 'John' })
/api/users?name=John&city=Berlin → User.find({ city : 'Berlin', name : 'John' })
```

Of course, you have to decide what should happen if *no* parameters are passed (in the example above, it would become a query that would match *all* users, which may not be what you want).

Also, you should probably filter `req.query` so it only contains fields that are defined in your schema.

Comment: ah cool, that's a start. But what if I don't test for equality, nor strings. 
So 

`{$or: [{undefined: {$eq: qP.ageLower}}, {'age': {$gte: parseInt(qP.ageLower)}}]}`

wouldn't work like this, right?
Also I'm having nestled fields I want to query. So the queryParameter `city` should actually test against `address.city`. Any ideas?

Comment: If you need more than simple equality checking you're going to have to process the incoming data anyway, or allow a more elaborate query format to be used ([`mongo-rql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-rql), [`monquery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monquery), [`mongo-querystring`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-querystring)).