# How to filter results by multiple query parameters if I don't know beforehand how many query strings I may receive from client side?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, query-string, querystringparameter

I want to send in response some data according to searching by query parameters (using .find function of mongoose) from the client side. What do I need to do is a search according to the parameters received?

What I mean is : 
I may receive

```
localhost:5000/admin/customers?customer_id=1&customer_email=abc@gmail.com
```

I could have used this code to send results according to this query :

```
Customer.find({
  customer_id = req.query.customer_id,
  customer_email = req.query.customer_email,
}, (err,docs)=> {
    res.json(docs);
})
```

or
   just

```
localhost:5000/admin/customers?customer_id=1
```

I could have used this code to send results according to this query :

```
Customer.find({
  customer_id = req.query.customer_id
}, (err,docs)=> {
    res.json(docs);
})
```

or
may be

```
localhost:5000/admin/customers?no_of_items_purchased=15
```

I could have used this code to send results according to this query :

```
Customer.find({
  no_of_items_purchased = req.query.no_of_items_purchased
}, (err,docs)=> {
    res.json(docs);
})
```

But what I want is to use .find function on anything received from query params. Like a general code to achieve this.

PS: Also please help with : "How to filter req.query so it only contains fields that are defined in your schema ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `query` variable to keep the field that you want to filter.

Suppose that your `Customer` model structure is:

```
{
  customer_id: ...,
  customer_name: ...,
  customer_email: ...,
  no_of_items_purchased: ...
}
```

Then your code will be:

```
let {customer_id, customer_name, customer_email, no_of_items_purchased} = req.query;
let query = {};
if (customer_id != null) query.customer_id = customer_id;
if (customer_name != null) query.customer_name = customer_name;
if (customer_email != null) query.customer_email = customer_email;
if (no_of_items_purchased != null) query.no_of_items_purchased = no_of_items_purchased;
let result = await Customer.find(query);
```

Comment: also please help with "How to filter req.query so it only contains fields that are defined in your schema ?"

Comment: `let {customer_id, customer_name, customer_email, no_of_items_purchased} = req.query;`. Notice this line, it only take the field you want from `req.query`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `request.query` as a parameter directly on find method:

`Customer.find(request.query)`